# Black background on any app window

Tags: finder, imac

Suddenly my computer (iMac 27" late 2012) screen appears like the screenshot I am attaching (happens with all apps)
Could it be just software issue that can be fixed or looks like a hw problem?
[image: screen]

Answer (score 1):

Looks like graphic distortion.  If [resetting NVRAM](http://support.apple.com/kb/ht1379) and [resetting SMC](http://support.apple.com/kb/ht3964) don't resolve the issue (and you don't have any other symptoms, e.g. crashing applications), visit the [Genius Bar](http://concierge.apple.com/reservation/us/en/techsupport/).

P.S.  If you feel up to the challenge, run [Apple Hardware Test](http://support.apple.com/kb/ht1509) and see what you find.  Then bring your results to your Genius Bar appointment.

Answer (score 0):

To rule out software:
* Create another user account and see if it happens there
* If it still happens, reinstall Mac OS X (have a good backup in case things go wrong)

Assuming you have already tried rebooting, I am curious what happens if you power off the iMac and let it remain powered off for a few hours, then try again (if at first it works, and then you get the black backgrounds after a while, that would indicate to me a heat-related issue).